# Add from datagridview to another datagridview using cell content click c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm a newbie in c# and I would like some assistance in handling the button in the datagridview.

The case is I have a Windows Form app that has 2 forms and a datagridview per form. One holds the company information and the other is where I send the company information. I would like to use the cell_content_click button located in the datagridview1 to transfer the whole row to datagridview 2 located in the Form2. I'd really appreciate the help and thanks in advance.

Here's the image of my form:
[image: CellContentClickFormSample]

Comment: Transfer data not a row.  One way is to use a pair of DataViews and a bool column to control which View the data appears in.  A simple Tab control might make things a little easier though

Comment: Thanks @Disaffected1070452! Really appreciated it.